# Visual studio 2017 Error - Cannot Find the specific File

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have been running into the same problem every time when I try to run a code. 
"Unable to start the program  ---- the system cannot find the specific file. 
I looked a different solution for previous versions of Visual Studio, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the problem that occurs:

[image]

Comment: Fix the compilation error 1st (see bottom right window).

Comment: Look at the Output window.  FAILED means that you can't run it yet.

Comment: The problem is tha your project is missing `stdafx.h`.  This file is auto-generated by MSVS.  The easiest fix - at least if you're relatively new to MSVS - is to simply create a new project, and copy/paste your source from the original, "corrupted" project.

Comment: Even when I remove the stdaf.h it doesn't work. I'm very new to Visaul Studio, and I'm lost. We jumped in class from doing basic things online, to dealing with files. All I'm trying to do is to use a text file. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: @LiorSh, also know that VS comes with a "VS Developer's Command-Prompt" that provides a pre-configured environment allowing you to build your application directly from the command line. That is instrumental in teaching you how to compile your code and learning the compiler and linker options. (`cl.exe` is the compiler) Then you can use the IDE much more effectively when you understand what it should be doing. (it's a lot faster too). For example, to compile a simple C++ file, you can simply `cl /nologo /W3 /FoYour.exe Your.cpp`. (where `/Fo` lets you specify your outfile name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is tha your project is missing `stdafx.h`. This file is auto-generated by MSVS.

1. The easiest fix - at least if you're relatively new to MSVS - is to simply create a new project, and copy/paste your source from the original, "corrupted" project.
2. Another solution is to disable "precompiled headers":

   > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7fz9ckx.aspx
   >
   > If you do not use precompiled headers in your project, set the
   >   Create/Use Precompiled Header property of source files to Not Using
   >   Precompiled Headers. To set this compiler option, follow these steps:
   >
   > 1. In the Solution Explorer pane of the project, right-click the project name, and then click Properties.
   > 2. In the left pane, click the C/C++ folder.
   > 3. Click the Precompiled Headers node.
   > 4. In the right pane, click Create/Use Precompiled Header, and then click Not Using Precompiled Headers.

   NOTE: If you choose to disable precompiled headers, then be sure to delete `#include "stdafx.h"` from all your source files.
3. For more information, look here:

   - [Precompiled Header Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h552b3ca.aspx)
   - [StdAfx.h for Novices](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2z86b7Xj/)

---

ADDENDUM:

1. Creating a new C++ project in Visual Studio *should* create a new stdafx.h.
2. Alternatively, "Setting Project > Properties > Precompiled headers > Not using Precompiled headers", then deleting `#include stdafx.h` from your .cpp files *should* fix the startup error.

... But there's also a third approach ...

3. You could *manually* create your own stdafx.* files and add them to the project.

   EXAMPLES:

stdafx.h:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files, or project 
// specific include files that are used frequently, but are changed infrequently
#pragma once

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

stdafx.cpp:

```
// stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes 
// hello_cpp.pch will be the pre-compiled header 
// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information
#include "stdafx.h"

// TODO: reference any additional headers you need in STDAFX.H // and not in this file
```

targetver.h:

```
#pragma once    
// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.

// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

Comment: I tried to create a new project, but the error keeps showing up. Thanks for your help and your time.